# String replace with regex doesn't work properly

Tags: java, regex

i'm trying to use iText to manipulate strings in my pdf, but i have a problem, when i set the regex expression in replace method it doesn't work.

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfDictionary dict = reader.getPageN(1);
    PdfObject object = dict.getDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);
    if (object instanceof PRStream) {
        PRStream stream = (PRStream)object;
        byte[] data = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
        stream.setData(new String(data).replace("^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\\/\\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\\/\\-]\\d{4}$", getData()).getBytes());
    }
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
```

It should change for example from 12/12/2018 into a date that i get with the method getData(), but in the new pdf there's still 12/12/2018, so i think regex isn't working.
Do you have any solution?

Comment: if you want regex replace you should `replaceAll` method.

Comment: Side note for future questions: "it doesn't work" doesn't help that much. You should at least tell us in what way it doesn't work, i.e. what you'd expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: And you should also provide [mcve] - over 90% of the code you have shown here is redundant and has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String#replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) does not support regex, it will try to replace your string literally, note the [`Pattern.LITERAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL) in the source code of `String#replace`:

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(
            this).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
}
```

---

The method you're looking for is [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) or [`String#replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), both of these take regex as input.

### Working example:

```
String regex = "^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\\/\\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\\/\\-]\\d{4}$";
String date = "12/12/2018";

System.out.println(date); // Prints 12/12/2018
date = date.replaceAll(regex, "myNewValue");
System.out.println(date); // Prints myNewValue
```

Comment: even with replaceAll and replaceFirst it doesn't work

Comment: @MassimoSimone How does it "not work"? When I create a minimal example with your regex, using `replaceAll`, and the input data being `12/12/2018` it works as expected.

Comment: ye, I know, I tested the regex online and it works, but in my java program not, it doesn't change strings in my pdf, if I set a static date to find it works fine.

Comment: @MassimoSimone Where are you putting this static date? Instead of `new String(data)`? or instead of `getData()`?

Comment: instead of the regex, like this  stream.setData(new String(data).replaceAll("12/12/2018", getData()).getBytes());

Comment: @MassimoSimone What's the content of `data`? In your regex you start with `^` and end with `$` which indicates it should match start and end, if `data` is anything other than literally `12/12/2018` removing `^` and `$` from your regex will cause it to work.